# Equivalent circuit of resistor in parallel with inductor

Tags: circuit-analysis

[image: this is register parallel with capacitor]

Anyone know where the value 120 + 240j comes from? This is a resistor in parallel with 300Ω inductor.

Comment: Did you mean "resistor" and "inductor"?

Comment: We aren't here to do your homework for you.

Comment: This really shows no effort. :|

Answer (score 3):

The net parallel impedance, Z is the product of the two impedances divided by their sum: -

Z = \$\dfrac{j 300\times 600}{600 + j300}\$

To evaluate this it is advisable to multiply the denominator by its complex conjugate: -

Z = \$\dfrac{j180000 \times (600 - j300)}{600^2 + 300^2}\$

This now equals \$\dfrac{54\times 10^6 + j108\times 10^6}{450000}\$

And, dividing through by 45000 yields: -

- real part is 120 ohms and
- imaginary part is 240 ohms

This is equivalent to a resistor of 120 ohms in series with an inductance having a reactance of 240 ohms.